# Why am I receiving a garbage value?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm very new to Assembly and cannot find the source of this bug after a good amount of debugging.

I have the following Assembly function. The goal is to calculate the value of x. All input variables are of type short and have values:

```
a = 3
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
e = -2
f = 5
```

The function is:

```
void calculate_x()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov     ax, c
        imul    e
        mov     numer, ax
        mov     ax, b
        imul    f
        sub     numer, ax

        mov     ax, a
        imul    e
        mov     denom, ax
        mov     ax, b
        imul    d
        sub     denom, ax

        mov     bx, numer
        idiv    bx
        mov     x, ax
    }
}
```

I'm getting a result of `x = 0` but it should be `x = 1`.

When I set breakpoints, the problem seems to lie in third to last line `mov     bx, numer`. This results in `bx` receiving a garbage value but it should receive a value of `-7`.

Why is `bx` receiving a garbage value?

Comment: How do you declare the static storage for these?  Any chance you got the sizes wrong?  You're clearly using MASM or something, not NASM, otherwise `imul f` would be an ambiguous operand size among other things.  So `mov bx, numer` isn't putting the address into the register.

Comment: Anyway, *what* garbage value?  Does it look like an address?  Is the low byte correct but not the high byte?  This isn't a [mcve] without that info. 
 And what value is in DX:AX before `idiv bx`?  You are intentionally leaving the 32-bit `imul` result in DX:AX, right?  Instead of doing 16-bit / 16-bit division.

Comment: Also, why are you dividing by the numerator?  I assume that's what `numer` is?  Division is `quotient = numerator / denominator`.  (And why are you loading `numer` into `bx` before idiv?  Is that just for debugging?  x86 has 8 or 16 registers; use them instead of memory.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for responding. The variables are being declared in C++ with `short a, b, c, d, e, f, x, y;`. I believe this is MASM as all of my Assembly code is inline in a C++ file. I'm using the __asm { <CODE HERE> } style and developing in Visual Studio. I have a nearly identical function to calculate a `y` variable and it is working just fine.

Comment: Oh, so this is inline asm?  Then show the whole function.  Is this Visual C++ compiling a 32-bit executable?  (In which case it's pretty much like MASM, but maybe allows C-style `0x123` hex instead of only `123h`.) Or are you using Turbo C++ or some other ancient 16-bit compiler?

Comment: @PeterCordes I've updated the post to show the entire function, but it isn't much more. I'm using the built in 'Build' command in Visual Studio Studio 2017 on a 64-bit computer so I'm guessing its generating a 64-bit executable?

Comment: So all your variables are globals?  You still left them out, along with how you're setting them, so this still isn't a [mcve].  Nobody could copy/paste this and try it on their own computer.  And you still left out what value `bx` actually gets.  (And BTW, your compiler is making a 32-bit executable.  MSVC only supports its clunky inline asm syntax in 32-bit mode.)  Does `numer` have the expected value of `c*e - b*f` after the first block of instructions?  I don't see any correctness problem with your code, just inefficiency like normal for beginner code, so the problem might be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `BX` receives the garbage, `AX` does it.  You calculate denom in memory but forget to reload it into DX:AX as the dividend for `idiv`.

Note that you need a valid value both in `DX` and `AX` for `IDIV`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

short a = 3;
short b = 1;
short c = 1;
short d = 1;
short e = -2;
short f = 5;

short x, numer, denom;

// (a*e - b*d) / (c*e - b*f)

void calculate_x()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov     ax, c
        imul    e
        mov     numer, ax
        mov     ax, b
        imul    f
        sub     numer, ax

        mov     ax, a
        imul    e
        mov     denom, ax
        mov     ax, b
        imul    d
        sub     denom, ax

        movsx   eax, denom
        cwd
        mov     bx, numer
        idiv    bx
        mov     x, ax
    }
}

int main()
{
    puts ("(a*e - b*d) / (c*e - b*f)");
    calculate_x();
    printf("%d / %d = %d", denom, numer, x);
    // note that numerator and denominator are misnamed.
    // we really are calculating denom / numer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for rearranging the brackets. How embarrassing!